# Async Response HTTP

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, spring-webflux

We are making a service that should accept HTTP requests.
This method should send client data to the Kafka “send” topic and forget about it for a little while (but not block)

```
@GetMapping("/comp")
public Mono<ShareObj> handleRequest() {
    CompletableFuture<ShareObj> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    ShareObj objectC = new ShareObj();
    objectC.setReq(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    kafkaTemplate.send("send", objectC);
    futureMap.put(objectC.getReq(), future);
    return Mono.fromFuture(future);
}
```

The data from the send topic was read and the response was sent to the "resp" topic. In the method where we have @GetMapping("/comp") there will be a @KafkaListener that listens to the topic "resp" from where we need to take data for the client.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "resp", groupId = "consGroup")
public void listen(@Payload ShareObj req) {
    System.out.println(req);
    var future = futureMap.get(req.getReq());
    if (future != null) {
        future.complete(req);
        futureMap.remove(req.getReq());
    }
}
```

I couldn't think of a better way than with CompletableFuture to return the response later. But there is a very bad throughput here.
How can you solve this problem in another way or in general some other approach?

Comment: Search for _long running http requests_.  Some basic approaches: 1) immediately return an ID from the initial HTTP request, and client itself listens to the topic with message including the ID; 2) immediately return an ID from the initial HTTP request, and the client periodically makes subsequent calls until the results are available (polling) for that ID; 3) as part of the initial request, the client provides a callback URL when the results are available.

Comment: @Andrew S Thanks for your ideas. But the client wants to work via scheme request-response(

Comment: btw, why `CompletableFuture` if you always convert it to a `Mono`? Did you consider using `Sinks.One`?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov
thanks, could you provide an example? I haven't worked with this yet

Comment: Like `Sinks.one()` instead of `new CompletableFuture<>()`, and deal that object instead. PS I'm not saying it fixes your problem, but it makes the implementation less complex as it drops an unnecessary intermediary

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Thanks, but its working the same like CompletableFuture(

Comment: right, you use it in the same way as a CompletableFuture. but it fits better the Reactor as it's a native component and doesn't need any wrapper